# Laravel 6 Unit Test file upload unable to find file at path

Tags: laravel, file-upload, faker, phpunit

I'm writing a unit test in laravel 6 to test file uploading.  I have a form that is creating a group and there is a file upload for covers.

My unit test is as follows

```
    $this->WithoutExceptionHandling();

    //login as admin
    $admin = $this->signInAsAdmin();

    Storage::persistentFake('public');

    $attributes =  [
        'group_name' => $this->faker->name,
        'group_description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
        'group_privacy' => '0',
        'group_cover' => $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('random.jpg')
    ];

    //create new group
    $response = $this->post('/admin/groups', $attributes);

    unset($attributes['group_cover']);

    Storage::disk('public')->assertExists($file);

    //check the data exists in database
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('groups', $attributes);

    //how is the uploaded file written to database

    //check the data exists in database
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('media', ['file_name' => $file]);

    //make sure the title appears on the group list
    $this->get('/admin/groups')->assertSee($attributes['group_name']);
```

The error I am getting is:

Unable to find a file at path [php624B.tmp].
Failed asserting that false is true.

I have also set in my php.ini file the upload_tmp_dir

upload_tmp_dir = C:\path_to_laravel_app\storage\tmp\uploads

What seems to be happening is that the faker library is not creating a temporary image. Doesn't matter what folder I set the tmp location to.

Any help would be appreciated

Danny